# Why I am not able to run Google Maps with AngularJS - JSFiddle from local?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I am trying to make the **Goole Map with Angular JS example** run in my local but not able to.
What is the problem?

**N.B.~** Since I am not able to put the links in the body (because it is complaining that if the link is of Plunker /JSfiddle, I have to put some code and indent it....I don't know how to do that in the body. So I am placing that in comment.

Comment: JSfilldle:  http://jsfiddle.net/pc7Uu/854/         plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/g4Z6ZOlJxnOeIo3RWeQh?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I guess "local" means your local filesystem(not a local webserver).

The issue is angular.js , it's included via:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.1/angular.min.js'></script>
```

as you see the protocol is missing, on your local filesystem the URL will be translated to

```
file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.1/angular.min.js
```

(where the script probably not exists)

yo must prepend the protocol to the URL:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.1/angular.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: yes  i tried the way has u  showed me but  its not  working still

Comment: Source of the fiddle(including the suggested modification): [**http://pastebin.com/CBVVDqCs**](http://pastebin.com/CBVVDqCs) .....works for me on my local filesystem